# Why are heavily downvoted questions not deleted?

Tags: discussion, questions, down-votes

If we sort questions by vote and go to the last page, one will find many questions with a score of -30.

Why are they kept? Shouldn't they be deleted?

Comment: Some have good answers that could be referred back to.

Comment: @SabreTooth My question recently got deleted though it had good answers.

Comment: if you mean your question here on MSE, then it was pure ranting/trolling and deleted by SE employee.

Comment: @ShadowWizard It had good answers .

Comment: So what? It was worthless to begin with.

Comment: Heavily downvoted questions are deleted automatically, if they meet certain criteria such as no upvoted answers.  They're of course not deleted *immediately*, but rather after some period of time.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Please look up my comment on James' answer .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What if you thought of asking the exact same question? Now you are warned not to, since the duplicate is already there. No matter how appreciated or not the question is, it serves a purpose.

And maybe the question has some excellent answers. If a question was downvoted for a lack of effort, being unclear at first, or any other reason, the answers could be useful to future reasons.

Answer (score 20):

Just because a question may have been bad, doesn't mean there isn't *some* value there. There could be great answers, for example, and deleting that content would deprive people from that knowledge.

And on a Meta site, where feature requests (as well as ill-considered discussions) can attract a lot of downvotes, it is important to keep posts around to show that the community consensus was against an idea. Deleting such posts would only lead to repeated discussions.

On the other hand, if a post has no value for *future visitors*, or attracts a lot of noise (spam, pointless discussions, flaming, etc.), it should just be deleted.

Answer (score 9):

> My question recently got deleted though it had good answers

FWIW - one of those answers was mine.

Your question was not constructive, didn't contain a "question", nor was it a point of potential useful discussion, as you asked nothing, proposed nothing, and simply stated "what is".
I answered to provide feedback, as there was nothing to help you with, and nothing to answer.

As for your attempt here to find some injustice from a -30 question being allowed to remain when yours was deleted, some questions, even though highly downvoted, provide reference and information useful to others.

Without their remaining, someone else might otherwise ask the same question, and we'd be forever answering the same old questions without even knowing it.
Which is just a waste of time.

Your question on the other hand offered no valuable keywords for future reference, and no useful ideas or suggestions.

Even if you didn't intend it to be a rant, it came across that way, as you simply stated a load of negative points about Stack, it's users, and Staff, and some of it was a bit close to the knuckle.

Comment: I didnt intend it to be a rant , maybe it appeared to be one in all the frustration . But to be honest , the many answers there ( including yours ) made me see some light . Rudeness is a minor  issue and mods do make mistakes as humans do . All in all consider this as an unofficial apology (to you and all others ) and my current rep status tells me that , after all those downvotes , the  SYSTEM IS FAIR !!

Comment: "*after all those downvotes , the SYSTEM IS FAIR*" The system is a set of basic guidelines, protocols, and tools. And, for the most part, it's all controlled and applied by "community" - that being all us users, including you. I believe the model works pretty well - certainly better in many ways than other models (forums with dictatorship moderating). Of course it's not perfect, as we are all people with different views. I disagree quite strongly with a few "policies", but ce la vie. FWIW, before I answered I upvoted your question - Couldn't find a dupe, and it's a good and valid  question.